# How to copy react build files in a web app with azure pipeline before release?

Tags: reactjs, build, azure-devops, copy, release

I set a build for a react web app in azure devops and another one for a web api application (c#). I would like to copy the output of the react build in the web api project before release them in Azure.  I tried with a copy task but i failed due to the web api application output (it's a zip). Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the project I'm on right now, this is solved by
1. building the front-end before building the web app project, and 
2. including the react-output-folder in the visual studio project, but using a wildcard, not each file:

```
<Content Include="webstorybook\*" />
```

By doing that, the files should be included in the published .zip file. Hope it works for you, too.

Comment: Thanks Snaits for your answer. In fact i want the copy files at the root of the web app but it's a good start.

Comment: Perhaps you can include ".\*.js" and ".\*.css" and whatever else you need in the project, I've never tried but worth a shot

Comment: In fact, the js files and css files have different names for each build (They're bundle and they have different names to avoid be cached).

Comment: That is the same scenario I have, and the wildcard solves that - try Include=".\\*.js" and Include=".\\*.css" and see if it works :)